# twitter api v1.1 statuses/update_with_media Missing or invalid url parameter

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

please help me i have a problem uploading image to twitter using api v1.1 
it was working perfect one month ago but it now doesn't work.
i'm using Abraham twitteroauth https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth
and i'm using enctype="multipart/form-data" as attribute in the form tag 
this is my code :

```
             require 'inc/twitter.class.php';   

             if(!empty($_FILES['media']['name'])){    // tweet with media
                  $file_name  = $_FILES['media']['name'];
                  $file_type  = $_FILES['media']['type'];
                  $file_size  = $_FILES['media']['size'];
                  $file_temp  = $_FILES['media']['tmp_name'];
                  $file_error = $_FILES['media']['error'];

                  $handle    = fopen($file_temp,'rb');
                  $image     = fread($handle,filesize($file_temp));
                  fclose($handle);
                  $tweet = new TwitterOAuth($YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY, $YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET, $row_user_info['access_token_oauth_token'], $row_user_info['access_token_oauth_token_secret']);
                  $result = $tweet->post('statuses/update_with_media',array('media[]' => "@{$image};type={$file_type};filename={$file_temp}",'status' => 'test'));

                  echo '<pre>';
                  print_r($result);
                  echo '</pre>';
```

the result is:

```
stdClass Object
(
[errors] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [code] => 195
                [message] => Missing or invalid url parameter.
            )

    )
)
```

i don't know what is missing in that
please help me

Comment: please help me i need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks very much but i edit the code and works fine now

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    // we set the type and filename are set here as well
                    $handle    = fopen($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],'rb');
                    $image     = fread($handle,filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
                    fclose($handle);
    $params = array(
      'media[]' => "@{$image};type={$_FILES['image']['type']};filename={$_FILES['image']['name']}",
      'status'  => $_POST['status']
    );
    $twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth($YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY, $YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET, $row_user_info['access_token_oauth_token'], $row_user_info['access_token_oauth_token_secret']);
    $dd = $twitteroauth->post('statuses/update_with_media',$params,true);

    var_dump($dd);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It was an issue with Abraham twitteroauth related to sending tweets with media. You can find fixed version of Twitteroauth here:

https://github.com/tomi-heiskanen/twitteroauth/blob/77795ff40e4ec914bab4604e7063fa70a27077d4/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php

Using this library you have to call:

```
$result = $tweet->post('statuses/update_with_media',array('media[]' => "@{$image};type={$file_type};filename={$file_temp}",'status' => 'test'), true);
```

The last parameter `true` means that you're sending multipart request.

Comment: i make like you said
it gives error

    Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: Unable to access ���� in /home/toptwet/public_html/inc/twitter.class.php on line 1094

in the function http

line 1094 is this line
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);

Comment: Did you included the last version of twitteroauth? Or maybe the path to file you're trying to access was changed?

Answer (score 1):

this work for me

---html---

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
      <label for="status">Tweet Text</label>
      <textarea type="text" name="status" rows="5" cols="60"></textarea>
      <br />

      <label for="image">Photo</label>
      <input type="file" name="image" />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

---php---

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
      // we set the type and filename are set here as well
      $params = array(
        'media[]' => "@{$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']};type={$_FILES['image']['type']};filename={$_FILES['image']['name']}",
        'status'  => $_POST['status']
      );

      $dd = $twitteroauth->post('statuses/update_with_media',$params,true);

      var_dump($dd);
}
```

use this modified library

https://github.com/tomi-heiskanen/twitteroauth/blob/77795ff40e4ec914bab4604e7063fa70a27077d4/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php

Comment: ok i have another problem i don't know sometimes you will have this problem i tried to add upload image function into reply from but it didn't work didn't you try it ?

Comment: this modified library saved me a lot of time, thanks!